# Return Slicer's Value (trade simulator)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I work with a single table (called `sTradeSim`) that I have created in PowerQuery. It has 3 columns (`Fund1`, `Fund2`, `Fund3`), each having values from -10 to 10, with an increment of 1.

[image]

I also have three separate slicers, each created using an option "Greater than or equal to". Each slicer is having a field assigned to it - Slicer 1 = Fund1, Slicer 2 = Fund2, Slicer 3 = Fund3. Below is a screenshot of Slicer 1.

[image]

Right next to these three slicers is a table with three rows. For each row, I would like to retrieve the value of the respective slicers. So the desired result would look like:

- Row No 1 = -10.00 (the value of Slicer 1),
- Row No 2 = -2.00 (the value of Slicer 2),
- Row No 3 = 3.00 (the value of Slicer 3).

Unfortunately, DAX formula that I have developed is always returning 3.00 (the value of the third slicer).

[image]

I have tried to find a solution on the forum and combine my SWITCH formula with ALL, ALLEXCEPT, SELECTEDVALUE etc., but it seems like I'm missing something very basic.

```
mHV_Trades =
SWITCH(
    MAX(FundTable[FundsRanked]),
    1, MIN(sTradeSim[Fund1]),
    2, MIN(sTradeSim[Fund2]),
    3, MIN(sTradeSim[Fund3])
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the issue is here but I'd suggest that if you want to control each fund independently, then the `Fund1`, `Fund2`, `Fund3` columns should be on independent tables so that filtering one fund doesn't affect the other ones.

Comment: Thanks @AlexisOlson, helpful as always. That makes sense. I wanted to avoid this solution as I have around 20-25 funds in my original report, which forces me to create 25 separate tables. I have edited my original post to show why I think SWITCH formula always returns 3.00 - as you said, it is probably caused by me using a single table. I'm happy to accept your solution if you post it here; are there any alternative solutions you can think of?

Comment: Why it should return - No 1 = -10.00, No 2 = -2.00, No 3 = 3.00? where as your SWITCH calculating MIN from fund1, fund2 and fund3 and for all 3 columns the MIN value is 3.0 as per your sample data.

Comment: Thanks for your time @R_R The idea for this report is to simulate trades, i.e. if a client holds 3 funds in a portfolio, I would need to have 3 slicers that will allow me to simulate buy/sell transactions, for each fund separately. For example, I might want to check what happens if I sell 5 millions of fund number 2, leaving fund 1 and 3 intact. That is why I need my DAX formula to return -10 for Fund no 1, -2 for Fund no 2 and 3 for Fund no 3, i.e. the values of each respective slicers, separately. I'm happy to try some other DAX formulas or solutions.

Comment: Requirement seems complicated to me. Sorry for that :( I think you can re visit your explanation in question and explain in steps as - First show your sample data, then show all 3 slicers sample screen shot and finally explain the output you need based on slicer selection wit logic. :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @R_R , of course I would like everyone to understand my question :-) I have edited my original post, hopefully it's a little bit clearer now. It's almost like I want these 3 columns to ignore each other, but I cannot figure out how to do it...?

Comment: I've attempted this before and failed. I don't think there's a good way to make columns operated independently of their table. That just not how tables work in Power BI, unfortunately. Independent parameters require independent tables.

Comment: Thank you @AlexisOlson I was so sure my approach would work, since DAX offers all the funky formulas like ALLEXCEPT, REMOVEFILTERS etc. But, as you said, columns cannot really be made independent of their table. I'm very glad you had time to look into this, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do doesn't work, because essentially when you place 1 filter on any column on the table, it will filter all the rows that have that value. So, when you apply a filter `fund1 = -10` it will also filter the values for `fund 2` and `fund 3`.

You have 2 options:

1. Create independent tables each with values from -10 to 10
2. Create a table with all the combinations of -10 to 10 values for every fund.

For your example with 3 funds this works quite nicely (the table has about 10k records), all the combinations of -10 to 10 (21) to the power of 3, the problem with this solution is that depending on the number of funds you have you will run out of space quite quickly.

Comment: Option 2 is a good one. I have tried and found the OP's requirements can be achieve this way. Here is the final output of my test work- https://imgur.com/a8MPnwh

Comment: Well it works for 3 slicers, but the table will grow exponentially for every additional slicer (6 slicers is 85 million rows!)

Comment: Thank you JoaoLeal and @R_R for your time & help. Now I know what my options and PBI's limitations are. It will allow me to assess which option should my company go for, given that we will be working with up to 20-25 funds; we would also need to assess what value range and increment we should go for. Much appreciated!